# Can I force Slack to display the user icon every time?

Tags: slack

I've got a bot that sends long messages.
When it sends multiple messages, the user icon often scrolls off the screen because no-one has sent a message between the bot's messages.

This means that it's less obvious when the message was sent and by whom.
Is there any way to force Slack to display the user icon for every message?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this by changing the name of the message sender to include some extraneous spaces. They seem to be considering messages from the same name to always have the same icon, but there are valid use cases for changing the icon on the fly with each message.

Comment: I really hoped there was a better answer but its the same thing I did. I just did random number between 1 and 99 which seemed sufficient for the frequency of my posts

Answer (score 1):

I tried padding the end of the message with empty whitespaces, but that doesn't seem to work anymore.

If you're ok with it, you can add a random number of whitespaces following by a full stop, or other character, like so:

`Product         .` renders as `Product .` in the slack client.

If you do a random number of spaces, it forces the user icon to be displayed every time, but still renders as though the whitespace has been striped.

Pretty grim, but works