# Is it possible to force Slack to Show app badge with each message?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am working on a Slack app that notifies my team at certain stages during a bash script. This script sends multiple messages in succession. It often happens that no one sends any messages in between the messages that my bash script sends. This means that App's the user icon often scrolls off the screen because no one has sent a message between the messages sent by my bash script.

Is there a way to force slack to attach the App's user icon to each message?

The only permissions my App has are `chat:write` and `incoming-webhook`. Due to internal security measures, these pretty much the only permissions I can give my App. I've also seen this question [Can I force Slack to display the user icon every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189336/can-i-force-slack-to-display-the-user-icon-every-time), but due to my limited permissions I can't use the username method.

I think that having my question answered will serve as a good update to the question I linked above, as that question was asked 6 years ago at the time of writing and a new method might be available.